# How do I access the component instance from code?

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-component-outlet

I am using an [`ngComponentOutlet`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet) to dynamically display a caller-supplied component. My code knows absolutely nothing about the supplied component type. The template boils down to this:

```html
<div [innerText]="options.title"></div>
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="options.componentType"></ng-container>
<button (click)="showInfo()">Info</button>
```

Speaking in a simplified manner, the caller for my UI passes a config object similar to the following:

```js
export interface DisplayOptions<TComponent> {
  readonly componentType: Type<TComponent>;
  
  readonly title: string;
  
  readonly onClickInfo: (cmp: TComponent) => void;
}
```

The UI surrounding the component outlet contains a couple of buttons, such as an *Info* button shown above. When that *Info* button is clicked, the `onClickInfo` function should be invoked, which needs to receive a reference to the component.

**Inside that `showInfo()` function, how do I get my hands on the reference to the component instance in the component outlet?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to get a reference to this component using a `@ViewChild`.

1. Make sure you have imported `NgComponentOutlet`.
2. Import ViewChild
3. Create a `@ViewChild` to get a reference to the component directive:

- `@ViewChild(NgComponentOutlet, { static: false }) ngComponentOutlet: NgComponentOutlet;`

4. Modify your show info:

- showInfo() {
  if (this.ngComponentOutlet) {
  const componentInstance = this.ngComponentOutlet['_componentRef'].instance;
  this.options.onClickInfo(componentInstance);
  }
  }

A full example would look something like this:

```
import { Component, Type, ViewChild, NgComponentOutlet } from '@angular/core';

export interface DisplayOptions<TComponent> {
  readonly componentType: Type<TComponent>;
  readonly title: string;
  readonly onClickInfo: (cmp: TComponent) => void;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic',
  template: `
    <div [innerText]="options.title"></div>
    <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="options.componentType"></ng-componentOutlet>
    <button (click)="showInfo()">Info</button>
  `
})
export class DynamicComponent<TComponent> {
  @ViewChild(NgComponentOutlet, { static: false }) ngComponentOutlet: NgComponentOutlet;
  options: DisplayOptions<TComponent>;

  showInfo() {
    if (this.ngComponentOutlet) {
      const componentInstance = this.ngComponentOutlet['_componentRef'].instance;
      this.options.onClickInfo(componentInstance);
    }
  }
}
```

You query the `ComponentOutlet` using the `@ViewChild` and store it in the `ngComponentOutlet` prop. `showInfo()` can then access the `['_componentRef'].instance` prop of `ngComponentOutlet`.

Another way to do this would be to go with an `@Input` which is similar, but you'd have to update the HTML and pass in a primary key that you can use like an Id.

Comment: This looks promising, I'm going to try this right away. However ... the `_componentRef` part is a bit hacky in that I'm accessing an internal field there, or does it just look like that?

Comment: Accessing a private property is a bit hacky, you're right. If you want to do it better, you can use `ComponentFactoryResolver`  and `ViewContainerRef ` to get a reference to the container where you want to insert the component.

Comment: Well, [that class](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactoryResolver) is marked as deprecated :/

Comment: Just read this in the docs: Note: since v13, dynamic component creation via ViewContainerRef.createComponent does not require resolving component factory: component class can be used directly. https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#createComponent

Comment: Does that mean I shouldn't be using an `NgComponentOutlet` at all in this situation, but instead trigger creation from code by means of a `ViewContainerRef` (I'd presumably obtain via a `@ViewChild` decorator targetting the prospective parent of the dynamically created component)?

Comment: Sounds like a great direction to try. let me know if it works out

Comment: Appears to work. The only slight conceptual difference, of course, is that the component is not instantiated automatically anymore as soon as the `ViewComponentRef` is assigned. This can be handled by placing the `@ViewChild` on a setter rather than a regular field, though. I've already accepted your answer, but adding a sentence about using a `ViewContainerRef` as an alternative solution would be appreciated for the sake of future visitors.