# How do I render a component dynamically and access their methods in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular2-template

I am using Angular 17 for a tiny app and I want to open different components (with forms) in a dialog window. The dialog itself is a wrapper which has two buttons, one of them should call a method of that component. I found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77283310/2776860

The comments says that it's a bit hacky but I cannot manage to solve it on another way? How can I create the component dynamically?

I want to access the component without this statement because it seems to be a bit hacky.
this.ngComponentOutlet['_componentRef'].instance;

My code looks like this:

Caller:

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private _dialog: MatDialog) {
  }

  openDialogOne() {
    const data: DialogData<FormComponent> = {
      headline: 'Form One',
      component: FormOneComponent,
    };

    this._dialog.open(DialogWrapperComponent, {
      width: '500px',
      height: '80vh',
      data
    });
  }

...
```

```
<button mat-flat-button color="primary" (click)="openDialogOne()">Dialog Form 1</button>
<button mat-flat-button color="primary" (click)="openDialogTwo()">Dialog Form 2</button>
```

Wrapper:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog-wrapper',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatDialogContent,
    MatDialogActions,
    MatButton,
    MatDialogClose,
    MatDialogTitle,
    NgComponentOutlet
  ],
  templateUrl: './dialog-wrapper.component.html',
  styleUrl: './dialog-wrapper.component.scss'
})
export class DialogWrapperComponent implements AfterViewInit{
  @ViewChild(NgComponentOutlet, { static: false })
  ngComponentOutlet!: NgComponentOutlet;

  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData<FormComponent>) {
  }

  submit(): void {
    if (this.ngComponentOutlet) {
      const componentInstance: FormComponent = this.ngComponentOutlet['_componentRef'].instance;
      componentInstance.submit()
    }
  }
}
```

Wrapper HTML:

```
<h2 mat-dialog-title>{{ data.headline }}</h2>
<mat-dialog-content>
  <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="data.component" ></ng-container>
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions>
  <button
    mat-flat-button
    mat-dialog-close>
    Cancel
  </button>
  <button
    mat-flat-button (click)="submit()">
    Install
  </button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the wrapper only use is to call methods from the child component, you can use the `EventBus` pattern using `rxjs subject` to emit and event from wrapper and receive it on the child! Working code below for your reference!

CHild component listening for event!

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DialogService } from '../dialog.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog-form1',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './dialog-form1.component.html',
  styleUrl: './dialog-form1.component.css',
})
export class DialogForm1Component {
  private subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();
  asdf: string = '123';
  submit() {
    alert('hello its me!');
  }

  constructor(private dialogService: DialogService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription.add(
      this.dialogService.subjectObservable$.subscribe((event: any) => {
        if (event.eventType === 'submit') {
          this.submit();
        }
      })
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

wrapper component emitting the event!

```
import { CommonModule, NgComponentOutlet } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Inject, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {
  MAT_DIALOG_DATA,
  MatDialogActions,
  MatDialogClose,
  MatDialogContent,
  MatDialogTitle,
} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatButton } from '@angular/material/button';
import { DialogForm1Component } from '../dialog-form1/dialog-form1.component';
import { DialogService } from '../dialog.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog-wrapper',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatDialogContent,
    MatDialogActions,
    MatButton,
    MatDialogClose,
    MatDialogTitle,
    CommonModule,
  ],
  templateUrl: './dialog-wrapper.component.html',
  styleUrl: './dialog-wrapper.component.scss',
})
export class DialogWrapperComponent {
  @ViewChild(NgComponentOutlet, { static: false })
  ngComponentOutlet!: NgComponentOutlet;

  constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
    private dialogService: DialogService
  ) {}

  submit(): void {
    this.dialogService.emit({ eventType: 'submit', data: {} });
  }
}
```

service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DialogService {
  private subject: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
  subjectObservable$!: Observable<any>;

  constructor() {
    this.subjectObservable$ = this.subject.asObservable();
  }

  emit(event: any) {
    this.subject.next(event);
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-hsy5gw?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdialog-wrapper%2Fdialog-wrapper.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdialog.service.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fdialog-form1%2Fdialog-form1.component.ts&template=node&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: Works like a charm and is a pretty good solution. Thanks a lot! :)